# How to add a null value in the group_concat if the record does not exist?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query with substring_index and group_concat but the results I get does not give the right location of the values because the values does not exist.

I need to add a null or zero value in order to have the right location of the values in the sql result.

In the table there are three lid (1, 2, 3). The lid should be the basis count of the P's (P1, P2, P3) for the substring_index.

**This is the table:**

```
lid   class_id   class          total   
-----  -------    -----        -----   
  1     73       Leader         10000      
  1     77       Consultant     8000       
  1     83       Coordinator    6000       
  2     73       Leader         20000      
  2     76       Staff          8000       
  2     77       Consultant     10000      
  3     73       Leader         30000      
  3     78       Team Leader    8000
```

This is the SQL query I used to group_concat for the totals and substring_index to separate the grouped values with their each column (P1, P2, P3)

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(lid) as lids, GROUP_CONCAT(pyear) as pyears, 
 COUNT(DISTINCT lib_id) AS total_count,
 CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>=1 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(if(total is null,0,total) ORDER BY lid ASC SEPARATOR ' '),' ',1),' ',-1) END AS P1, 
 CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>=2 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(if(total is null,0,total) ORDER BY lid ASC SEPARATOR ' '),' ',2),' ',-1) END AS P2, 
 CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>=3 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(if(total is null,0,total) ORDER BY lid ASC SEPARATOR ' '),' ',3),' ',-1) END AS P3
 FROM ( 
  SELECT * FROM view_items WHERE lid='1' 
  UNION 
  SELECT * FROM view_items WHERE lid='2' 
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM view_items WHERE lid='3' 
 ) AS AZ GROUP BY class_id
```

**This is the result of the above query:**

```
class id    class         lids     P1      P2      P3
---------   -----        -----    ----    ----     ----            
   73      Leader         1,2,3   10000   20000   30000  
   76      Staff          2       8000   
   77      Consultant     1,2     8000    10000   
   78      Team Leader    3       8000             
   83      Coordinator    1       6000
```

The lids should always have three count even though the record does not exists, a zero or null value should be added. How to do the adding of null value?

**This is the expected result I need.**

```
 class id    class         lids     P1      P2      P3
---------   -----        -----    ----    ----     ----            
   73      Leader         1,2,3   10000   20000   30000  
   76      Staff          0,2,0     0     8000      0
   77      Consultant     1,2,0    8000   10000     0
   78      Team Leader    0,0,3     0       0      8000             
   83      Coordinator    1,0,0    6000     0       0
```

Comment: Alternatively, consider handling display issues in application code, if that's available

Comment: Do you have any class table where all classes are listed?

Comment: Yes, there is a class table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get 0 values where no `lid` is present in the table, you need to generate a list of all `lid` values for all `class_id` values, which you can do with a `CROSS JOIN` of two `SELECT DISTINCT` queries (one for `lid`, one for `class_id`). This can then be `LEFT JOIN`ed to the table, to get the required `total` value for each `P` group using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.class_id,
       MAX(v.class),
       GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(v.lid, 0) ORDER BY l.lid) AS lids,
       MAX(CASE WHEN v.lid=1 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS P1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN v.lid=2 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS P2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN v.lid=3 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS P3
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT lid FROM view_items) l
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT class_id FROM view_items) c
LEFT JOIN view_items v ON v.lid = l.lid AND v.class_id = c.class_id
GROUP BY c.class_id
```

Output:

```
class_id    class       lids    P1      P2      P3
73          Leader      1,2,3   10000   20000   30000
76          Staff       0,2,0   0       8000    0
77          Consultant  1,2,0   8000    10000   0
78          Team Leader 0,0,3   0       0       8000
83          Coordinator 1,0,0   6000    0       0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ithF3xK3vT7HUhfzvBUS7i/0)

Comment: Awesome! thanks for that dbfiddle... I just customize a little bit and retained the UNION, it's something I need to get the right values.

Answer (score 1):

Use `else 0` in `case expression`

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(lid) as lids, GROUP_CONCAT(pyear) as pyears, 
 COUNT(DISTINCT lib_id) AS total_count,
 CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>=1 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(if(total is null,0,total) ORDER BY lid ASC SEPARATOR ' '),' ',1),' ',-1) else 0 END AS P1, 
 CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>=2 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(if(total is null,0,total) ORDER BY lid ASC SEPARATOR ' '),' ',2),' ',-1) else 0 END AS P2, 
 CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>=3 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(if(total is null,0,total) ORDER BY lid ASC SEPARATOR ' '),' ',3),' ',-1) else 0 END AS P3
 FROM ( 
  SELECT * FROM view_items WHERE lid='1' 
  UNION 
  SELECT * FROM view_items WHERE lid='2' 
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM view_items WHERE lid='3' 
 ) AS AZ GROUP BY class_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, that you say count >= 1, but count >= 3 is also count >=1 so your code never reaches this line. You have to say, 
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >=1 AND COUNT (*) < 2...
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >=2 AND COUNT (*) < 3...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `GROUP_CONCAT()` is the right approach for what you want.  Try this:

```
SELECT vi.class_id, vi.class,
       COUNT(DISTINCT vi.lib_id) AS total_count,
       CONCAT_WS(',',
                 MAX(CASE WHEN vi.lid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
                 MAX(CASE WHEN vi.lid = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
                 MAX(CASE WHEN vi.lid = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                ) as lids,
       SUM(CASE WHEN vi.lid = 1 THEN vi.total ELSE 0 END) as total_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN vi.lid = 2 THEN vi.total ELSE 0 END) as total_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN vi.lid = 3 THEN vi.total ELSE 0 END) as total_3
FROM view_items vi
WHERE vi.lid IN (1, 2, 3) 
GROUP BY vi.class_id;
```

Notes:

- Your subquery and `UNION` are not needed.  In MySQL, these can actually *hurt* performance.
- I assume that `lid` is a number, so I've removed the single quotes.
- You can use conditional aggregation for each of the totals that you want.  Parsing `GROUP_CONCAT()` is not the right way to do this.
- Your question is about the `lid`s.  The `CONCAT_WS()` does what you want -- concatenating either the value (if it appears) or zero if it does not.